# OpenVPN route IPV4 over IPV6

Tags: openvpn

A friend of mine has issues with his ISP. At the moment, he get's no IPV4 from his provider (they have issues since 2 weeks), but one IPV6. Sadly, it's not possible to open 95% of the websites without an IPV4 address.

Is it possible to connect through IPV6 to my OpenVPN server and use an IPV4 address from the OpenVPN server to connect to websites etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use IPv6 as the OpenVPN transport protocol (`proto udp6`) in OpenVPN configuration.

Then, you can tunnel IPv4 via the OpenVPN tunnel. You need to set up NAT in your end, so that the traffic coming from your friend gets correctly routed via your IPv4 connection.

So, the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

Not without any additional configuration: you need a NAT64 gateway. You could setup one yourself using a tool like [Tayga](http://www.litech.org/tayga/) or use a publicly available one (without needing to build the OpenVPN tunnel) like [nat64.net](http://nat64.net).